# Why does the resolution decrease with increasing incidence angle in the Sentinel-1 SAR sattelite

Tags: remote-sensing, satellite, resolution, angles, sentinel-1

On this link (`Sentinel1` [webpage](https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-1-sar/resolutions/level-1-single-look-complex) for a `SLC` product), the `resolution` is written as a range from the highest corresponding to low `incidence angle`, to the lowest `resolution` corresponding to high `incidence angle`.

My question is how is the `resolution` related in general to the `incidence angle`? And if they are really related, why is the `resolution` affected by the change in the `incidence angle`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Think of the geometry. The incidence angle refers to the angle from nadir, or directly beneath the satellite, which would be 0°. As the sensor looks out to the sides from this nadir, the angle of incidence increases as does the fov (field of view). This is why the resolution decreases with increase in incidence angle. This illustration from the Sentinel website might help to visualize this concept.

[image]

Comment: According to the illustration above, as `FOV` (or `incidence angle`) increases, the `swath` increases too. But, does an increase in the `swath` mean a decrease in the `resolution`, and why? Thanks.

Comment: It helps to think of the sensor like an imaging sensor of a digital camera in the sense that there is only a finite amount of information it can receive: If you zoom in (decrease in swath width) you'll cover a smaller area with the same amount of pixels and if you zoom out (increase in swath width) you'll cover a larger portion of the earth with the same amount of pixels.

Comment: There are two parts to the idea of resolution and angle.  The first is the sensor, as @Kersten mentioned.  The second part is that this is radar, and you are trying to capture reflections of an emitted signal.  The closer you are to directly above something, the more waves fall on a given area and are reflected straight back at you, increasing the odds that they will be picked up by the sensor.  With a larger angle, the waves encounter a larger surface area on the ground, and the potential for scatter, or waves reflected in different directions, increases.  Both factors reduce resolution.

Comment: @GetSpatial I do not see the connection between resolution and amount of reflected energy.  The resolution will be what it is, based on the geometry as described here and the characteristics of the sensing system (including the sensor). The amount of reflected energy will determine the quality of the image--its brightness and contrast in particular--but will not change the inherent resolution of the system.

Comment: @whuber I think that what was meant is not the `reflected energy` per `pixel` (or any other unit) but the `quantity` of information returned to the sensor instead (depending on the `resolution` and the `swath`).

Comment: @h4k1m Could you elaborate on the distinction you are making between the energy absorbed per pixel and "quantity of information" (presumably, per pixel)? Regardless, if we are to understand--as is conventional--that "resolution" refers to the amount of space on the earth's surface contributing to the response of a given pixel, the amount of energy (or number of photons) actually causing that response would seem not to be part of the concept of "resolution," but instead is dependent on the resolution.

Comment: @whuber according to what I understood, the `SAR` sensor illuminate for a limited amount of `time`, with a limited amount of `energy`, the `swath` to be imaged. Whether the illuminated swath is coarse (large `incidence angle` & lower `resolution`) or narrow (small `incidence angle` & higher `resolution`), the quantity of energy transmitted is the same. It's not the energy absorbed per pixel that is constant (since the `resolution` is affected by the `swath width`), it's the total energy transmitted by the sensor (which doesn't change while the `swath width is changed).

Answer (score 2):

One short comments regarding your other questions: [Why is azimuth resolution worse than range resolution in Sentinel1 (SAR)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157024/why-is-azimuth-resolution-worse-than-range-resolution-in-sentinel1-sar?lq=1)

You are absolutely right that sentinel TOPS have a worse azimuth resolution comparing with other data. This exactly the unique characteristic of TOPS. The working mode of TOPS (also including ScanSAR) is designed to sacrifice azimuth resolution to increase SAR image coverage on range direction.